# Create a frame with angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to create something like the official page og angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api
on the left the are using a kind of "frame". How can I get something like that ? 
I tried bg-splitter and angular ui layout but I am note sure if it's the right way to do  it ? 
Another short question, the list of element on the left (the frame) is made in a single view right ?

Comment: This is just CSS using overflow: scroll or auto on the left element.  Open up you dev tools and inspect the elements.  You can basically copy the CSS directly out of the docs to reproduce.